# Spartacus 6.6.x compatibility with SAP commerce (on premise) 2205

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I'm aware that since I'm using non-cloud Hybris version, self publishing of spartacus libraries will be necessary.

But question is if 6.6x (or any other version 6) is compatible with SAP commerce (on premise) 2205 and production ready?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has release version for 6.x and 6.6.x. They already mention that in [the document](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/tree/release/6.6.x) it is compatible with 2005 and never versions.